# Apply css style for ol and li for different sections in html

Tags: html, css

I need to apply multiple `<ol>` and `<li>` style to different sections in the HTML file.  I created a class name `.itemListing` in the STYLE section and specified that class in a div.  But it does not apply.  I only want to apply this itemListing style in one section only.

Any suggestions?

Here is part of the HTML:

```
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <TITLE></TITLE>
    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
    .itemListing
    {
        ol {
                counter-reset: item;
                margin-left: 0;
                padding-left: 0;
            }
        li {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: .5em;
            margin-left: 2em;
        }
        li:before {
            display: inline-block;
            content: "Item "counter(item) ": ";
            counter-increment: item;
            width: 7em;
            margin-left: -2em;
        }
    }
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">

<div class="itemListing">
<FONT COLOR="#0000ff">There are two items:</FONT><BR>
<ol>
<li> This is one item listing.</li>
<li> This is another item listing.</li>
</ol>
</div>
<BR>

<FONT COLOR="#0000ff">This is a different listing:</FONT><BR>
<ol type="A">
<li>&nbsp;This item listing will have different format. </li>
<BR>
</ol>
```

Comment: That's not valid CSS. That looks like some sort of precompiler like sass. And on a side note, the `<font>` element was deprecated decades ago.

Comment: You're trying to style all the lists contained within the `div.itemListing` right?

Comment: To expand on @j08691 - There's nothing wrong with pre-compilers, but they happen outside of the HTML page. You can't run a pre-compiler inside HTML. Using LESS or SASS means that you write the file, something compiles it, and spits out a valid CSS file. Then you need to link that CSS file into your HTML file. You can't write LESS/SASS directly inline.

For your <font> tags, you need to wrap those in a <p> or <span> and add a class or style attribute to it to style the color.

Comment: The [<font> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is obsolete and should not be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define your styles like this

```
.itemListing ol {
            counter-reset: item;
            margin-left: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
    .itemListing li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
    .itemListing li:before {
        display: inline-block;
        content: "Item "counter(item) ": ";
        counter-increment: item;
        width: 7em;
        margin-left: -2em;
    }
```